# multiple socket events sent instead of one

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I have problems understanding the basic idea of sockets. I think the following example descibes my problem best.

**The onConnection function does nothing but sending an Event to all connected clients.**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    io.sockets.emit('myEvent');
});
```

**Those Clients create a li-element for each received event.**

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('myEvent', function(){
  $('#list').append($('<li>').text('myEvent received'));
});
```

*First* Client A connects.  *Then* Client B connects.

**What I expected:**

*First* client A sees one li-element

*Then* client A sees two li-elements and client B sees one li-elements

**What actual happend:**

*First* client A sees one li-element

*Then* client A sees three li-elements and client B sees two li elements

Why do the clients receive the "old" event from the client A connection again when client B connects? Is this the normal socket behaviour? Why is this? Is there any why i can get my expected behaviour?

Comment: Try sending incrementing numbers down to the myEvent function, and post the results. I'm thinking Client A might be reconnecting.

Comment: @Danbopes Yep you are right. I added the client name and the number of connections and the result looks like this:

**Client A**

CLIENT A 1

CLIENT A 2

CLIENT B 1

**Client B**

CLIENT A 2

CLIENT B 1

Comment: But why does client a reconnect when client b connects? And why is there still the first entry (CLIENT A 1) after the reconnect?

Comment: the first entry is added the first time, you just don't remove it from the list before the 2nd one is added. i would not use the connection events, but rather manually send an event from the client once it's connected.

Comment: Alright everything makes perfect sense now :) Thanks to both of you!